# How to delete file after closed that file process in C#

Tags: c#, file

I want to delete a file. But it cannot do because it use another process. 
Error message :

```
"The process cannot access the file '*file path\4.JPG*' because it is being used by another process."
```

My program's description is,suppose  I copy a image into one common file. then if I want to delete ths image from common folder, then error message will generate. file.Delete(..) is not working in my code.

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure do you want to delete this recorde?","Delete",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (result.ToString().Equals("Yes"))
        {
            string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM dbo.fEmployee WHERE EmpId=@empId";
            SqlParameterCollection param = new SqlCommand().Parameters;
            param.AddWithValue("@empId",cmbEmpIdD.SelectedValue);
            int delete = _dataAccess.SqlDelete(deleteQuery,param);
            if (delete>0)
            {
                **ImageDeletion();**
                MessageBox.Show("Recorde Deleted sucessfully.","Delete",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else if (delete.Equals(0))
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Recorde is not deleted.","Falied",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
    }


    private void ImageDeletion()
    {
        string ext;
        ext = Path.GetExtension(txtImgPathD.Text.Trim());
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ext))
        {
            string path = appPath + @"\" + @"EmployeeImages\" + cmbEmpId.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() + ext;
            PictureBox.InitialImage = null;
            PictureBox.Invalidate();
            PictureBox.Image = null;
            PictureBox.Refresh();
            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
```

Please give me a solution for the delete a file part.
Thank you!

Comment: `result.ToString().Equals("Yes")` - The pain! Use `result == DialogResult.Yes`.

Comment: You would have to identify which process has the file locked and get it to release its lock (or terminate the process). It *is* possible to close other processes file handles (the app 'Unlocker' does this, for example) but it is not trivial.

Comment: you can use ResourceMonitor or proccess explorer to see the open file handles

Comment: Since this hasn't been solved yet apparently: You need to show us how the image file is opened by your program in the first place, otherwise we can just guess.

Comment: Show us how you open the image file.

Comment: This code is used to show image in picture box.
            OpenFileDialog selectImg = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (selectImg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.PictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(SourcePath);
                this.PictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(this.PictureBox.Image, new Size(217, 178));
            } After this I was copied my image into another folder using bellow code :                         File.Copy(sourcePath, dest..Path,true); Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The error message here is telling you all you need to know - something has hold of your file so you cannot delete it.

Have you opened the file elsewhere in your application and not closed the filestream correctly, perhaps?

Comment: Thakn you @BrianC . but I am not using FileStream. I only display that copied image in PictureBox. After this PictureBox.Image = null; I was tried to delete that image in common folder. But it cant. this copied image is not used another process. Its only show in the picturebox. but I clear picturebox before delete the file. but its not working. Anyway Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try disposing the image in the `PictureBox`.

```
PictureBox.Image.Dispose();
```